# Abi Decode raw types with Go

Tags: go-ethereum, abi

I have a simple abi.encoded string `data` that has a series of raw types. In solidity I would decode `data` by using the `abi.decode` function.

```
(uint256 total, uint256 id) = abi.decode(data, (uint256, uint256))
```

Is there a way to do the same in golang. I can do it if I have a contract abi but don't understand how to do it with the primitive types.

I was looking at the code for `abi.NewType` but I think that may be a redherring

The same functionality in ethers is https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/abi/coder/

Answer (score 1):

You can use go-web3, check the example in the github repository for abi, it is easy to understand https://github.com/umbracle/go-web3#abi.

To modify for your example of 2 uint256:

```
typ := abi.MustNewType("tuple(uint256 a, uint256 b)")

type Obj struct {
    A *big.Int
    B *big.Int
}


obj := &Obj{
    A: big.NewInt(2),
    B: big.NewInt(1),
}

// Encode
encoded, err := typ.Encode(obj)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// Decode output into a map
res, err := typ.Decode(encoded)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: Awesome. I do wonder how with geth directly

Comment: @user87652 for that you can check out the test on their github right here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/accounts/abi/abi_test.go.  import "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi" and you are good to go